# Formatting currency with two decimal places

Tags: format

When formatting a cell as currency with two decimal place, the value shows something different when increasing to 12 or more decimal places.

Example:

A dollar value of $268.97. I type in 268.97, it's formatted as currency, 2 decimal places, then I increase the decimal places to 13 and the cell now shows $268.9699999999990.

Why does this happen? I only see this anomaly when formatting currency. And the two values 'do not' equal each other.

Answer (score 0):

> the value shows something different when increasing to 12 or more
> decimal places

That is entirely normal. Formatting a cell does not change the true value of the contents of the cell.

If you wish to have just two decimals for a currency amount, then use the Round function to round to 2 decimals.

Save your work when done.

Remember that spreadsheets use complete number capacity so it is possible after rounding that you may see xx99999999 or xx00000001 . Nothing can be done about that.

Round as you need to and format the cell to 2 figures and then just continue on.

Comment: As a work-around, I do indeed use the round function to get the values to equal each other. Maybe you don't understand my problem. I type in a value with two decimal places, not 12 decimal places. But its value does indeed change when I increase the decimal places to 12. I use the increase decimal icon to do this (won't copy in when using the snipping tool.

Comment: After you Round, then the 12 digit value should be like  26.430000000  . If you get a value like  xx9999999 or xx00000001   then that is just the numerical value internally. Nothing you can do about that.  Use your spreadsheet for this, not the snipping tool as spreadsheets use total internal number capacity.

Comment: Why does the numerical value change internally? That's the million dollar question! If I type in $44.11, I expect Excel to recognize and use that value and not represent it as $44.1099999999999. Why does the internal value need to change? It doesn't always change, just sometimes and that is puzzling. PS - you didn't understand my reference to my snipping tool remark. I tried to snip in the icon to show you what I use to increase decimals but it wouldn't paste in to my response.

Comment: @gjls10 The floating point number 44.11 cannot be stored exactly in the system unless you're using [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal) and this is moderately rare. So 44.11 is never stored internally as those four decimal digits. 44.11 may be stored as very slightly less, 44.12 as very slight more. You have to delve into the binary representation of the decimal to know for certain.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has the true answer 'inside' the technology used to represent numbers in computers.

The problem is similar to the fact that the result of `one divided by three` cannot be written out on paper with all decimals, i.e. `0.3333333<append '3' any _finite_ number of times>` is only APPROXIMATELY equal to `1/3`.

Inside computers `1/10`, `1/100` and so on has the same problem; it cannot be represented EXACTLY in the same manner *(using base two, with zeroes and ones)*.

Therefore the problem is present in the "floating point" -numbers that is used in Excel and most other computer software packages.

*What you see is a side effect of that.*

**Ref:**
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic
*You may probably find a load of literature on creation of numeric representation in computers. This area of knowledge includes lengthy texts within 'Discrete mathematics'.*

*Excel uses double precision floating point numbers, which have a limit somewhere near "16 digits" e.g. type in a series of decimal as in `0.1234567890123456...` and you will see some of the last ones dropped off. There are tricks here though, you may read about those under the Ref link.*

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation. I completely understand your response. But shouldn't this 'side effect' happen each and every time? It does not. It seems that it happens randomly. I have been trying for a long time to re-create this 'side effect' at will but can not and that really puzzles me. One would think this 'side effect' would be constantly observed for cases such as 1/3 and other fractions but it isn't. Something is going on inside excel at the 12th decimal point, not 11 or 13, but 12. I consider this 'side effect' to be very dangerous especially in the financial world.

Comment: The explanation to that is elaborated in `Discrete mathematics`, in there are techniques which minimizes the problem. I cannot (i.e. do not know how to) explain in a few words.

Comment: I'd say that software for the financial world would not use floating point, e.g. for serious book keeping. Read about alternative techniques under the provided Ref.

Comment: Yes, formulas used for the financial world should be done using math libraries made for that purpose. Many programmers and users do not realize this. Excel does take reasonable precautions, but end-users sometimes make the mistake of using excel for purposes it ought not be used for (i.e. matlab or something else is probably a better fit for analysis)